# How can run functions of powercfg by C# code?

Tags: c#, .net, powercfg

how can run functions of powercfg by c# code?
for example I want to run this, for Set turn off the display: never

```
powercfg -CHANGE -monitor -timeout -ac 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call it with [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx):

```
Process.Start("powercfg", "-CHANGE -monitor -timeout -ac 0");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can call [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) to run an executable.

For example:

```
Process.Start(fileName: "powercfg", arguments: "-CHANGE -monitor -timeout -ac 0");
```

---

However, if you're only trying to disable auto-off while your program is running, you should handle the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message instead.

For example:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    const int SC_SCREENSAVE = 0xF140, SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170;
    const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;

    if (m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND) {
        if ((m.WParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFF0) == SC_SCREENSAVE || (m.WParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFF0) == SC_MONITORPOWER) {
            m.Result = 0;
            return;
        }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class to run powercfg from C#.